# Jade language injection in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I have an HTML element whose contents I want to be treated as Jade (it will be compiled to pure html later). Webstorm obviously doesn't recognise this so it has no syntax highlighting:

[image]

If I go to add jade as a language injection, it isn't listed as one of the possible language injections.

[image]

However Jade files are recognized fine by webstorm.

[image]

Is there any way to add Jade as a possible language injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jade is not an injectable language, it's a templating language that can only be used as a 'master' language for other languages. So the answer is 'no'.
If you miss a possibility to  inject template languages, please follow [IDEA-106449](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106449) for updates